# Close fancybox after mediaelement.js video ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I am using fancybox to display a video using mediaelement.js My client wants fancybox to automatically close after the video completes.  I have the following code from mediaelement.js with a listener event for the end of the video [here](http://pastebin.com/WGeFw1vg)

I am just not sure what to put in that function to close the fancybox window at the end of the video playing. I am a bit of a novice when it comes to javascript. Your assistance is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: By looking at the [Fancybox API](http://fancybox.net/api), I can see a `$.fancybox.close` method...

Comment: I got this working using the html5 video player in MediaElements, however when added the listener for the ended it no longer works with the flash player. pastebin.com/bxAH2m5N I also just posted the full code of the page at pastebin.com/aqSppHvy That file is what fancy box is calling in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fancybox.close
```

or if in an iframe

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: I got this working using the html5 video player in MediaElements, however when added the listener for the ended it no longer works with the flash player. http://pastebin.com/bxAH2m5N I also just posted the full code of the page at http://pastebin.com/aqSppHvy  That file is what fancy box is calling in the iframe.